# Kafka broker on EC2 is not connecting to my zookeeper on my local network

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-consumer-api

Guys if someone has experienced this issue - please can you help me - i have been racking my brains on this with no success and have pored over as many posts as i can.

**Scenario**
I have zookeeper / two brokers and a producer and consumer running on my local partition from different IP addresses within my subnet and everything is perfect.  My producer produces - consumer consumes life is happy.

I wanted to replicate this on EC2 an spun up a kafka broker on EC2 and want that broker to connect to my zookeeper but for some reason the broker on EC2 is unable to connect to my zookeeper.

Now for clarity sake :
My laptop IP :1.1.1.1  (1) in the attached image
Zookeeper IP: z.z.z.z.z (2) in the attached image
Broker 1 on my laptop : b.b.b.b.b

So the issue is from EC2 when i try connecting to zookeeper i get an error and time out - I do not understand what is going on also i have opened ports/IP to my laptop and have these in my inbound outbound sessions.

Please can someone help - also i dont understand why Kafka broker on EC2 is trying to connect to
z.z.z.z.us-east-2.compute.internal ....

Forgive me guys but I am not sure if / what i need to change.

In the broker config :
i have zookeeper config set as z.z.z.z:2181,1.1.1.1:2181

From EC2 teerminal i can ping my laptop public DNS - but cannot ping my internal partitioned IP on which zookeeper is running - i think this may be a cause also.

If you can please help shed some light on this and if u r in NY - beers on me.

Thank you !!!!

[Screen shot of EC2 Kafka log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pXDe.jpg)

Comment: All the examples I have found are setting up Kafka clusters and zookeeper and producer / consumer on EC2.

I think for my scenario i need to do port forwarding of my local zookeeper so that EC2 can connect to my local zookeeper IP/port.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**
I could not find a definitive answer - i went over the docs - so i took a step back and started checking the logs.
This is what i found :

ssh / scp works from my zookeeper to EC2 but not from EC2 to zookeeper
zookeeper is on manjaro dedicated IP on my subnet

So fundamentally the issue is i did not have a port open
So i opened a port on my router updated (very important) the ip address in EC2 server.properties to have my public IP w the assigned port which i opened and forwarded to my Kali (stopped Majaro spun up Zookeeper on Kali)  IP and 2181

Worked like a charm - EC2 was able to connect to zookeeper - all good.

Now from my Fedora i fired up a producer and got EC2 to consume - confirmed in logs plus in CMAK.

But from my Ubuntu consumer even though i see the consumer was able to connect i am unable to consume messages and consumer group not being able to create.

So some findings here :

1. Do not use Manajaro - use Kali - i am not 100% sure for the reason but my yum update resulted in Kali zookeeper to be able to more easily connect to EC2 - plus i can configure Kali more easily - i am pretty sure both are the same but i found it easier to navigate Kali than Manjaro.  So i have zookeeper on Kali - and more i use Kali i am loving it - i can run my python socket scripts from Kali on my router and create a new subnet inside Kali - which i could not from Manjaro - fundamentally wanting to run another broker on the same partition / box.
   So Kali thumbs up then Fedora, LinuxMint then Ubuntu then Manjaro - again I am 100% sure i am doing something very stupid and this is no reflection on these distributions its just my personal opinion on using them.  Plus for some reason i get more info with sudo tracert on Kali than Manjaro - all in all Manjaro i am going to hut down and not touch / use too much time waste (IMHO) its too GUI driven ...
2. On Manjaro for some reason the IP was set to DHCP and kept on flipping and i also found if the IP flips for some reason i need to flush non committed messages on a topic and create a new cluster and then a new topic in CMAK - i am not sure why this wuld be the case - i am using 2.7.0.
3. Also - since i did not want to spend $$ on EC2 i am spun up the basic Amazon Linux2 and then created my own AMI w Java / Python (note yum works on Python 2 so u need to relink to Python 2 to do any yum updates and then link to 3.7) / Kafka - but all in all i had to set broker mem to 128M / 526M because of obvious limitation and because i wanted to use the free service from AWS) - so i think the reason my consumer connected but failed to  consume any messages was because of throughput and network bandwidth - also i think i made a mistake - shud have used zone N Virginia instead of Ohio being in NY.
4. From what i have read so far - what i was trying to do w Port forwarding essentially is not recommended and Kafka docs specifically state that to do this in a trusted netwrork in a VPN etc etc - but I had to test to make sure it worked - just a proof of concept
5. on EC2 the system works perfectly soup to nuts no issues.

So issue resolved - but will need to check thruput on ubuntu for consumer why i could not register a consumer group - but thank you all in all what i wanted to test worked.